# How do I keep my CSS links in the head section for Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I want to have action specific CSS, meaning that it would only link the CSS for the actions that uses it (also for my jQuery stuff). Currently, I am just putting `$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/basic.css')` in the view file of the action that needs the CSS. However, when I look at the source, it's just out of place and I want it to be in the head section. I can load it up in the bootstrap, but I do not want to link unnecessary things for unrelated actions. Is there a way for me to load my action-specific CSS in the head section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your head section just

```
<?php echo $this->headLink(); ?> //for css
```

if you want to  link js files then

```
<?php echo $this->headScript() ; ?> // for js
```

Appending file in the phtml side

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl.'/js/yourjs.js'); ?> //js
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl.'/css/yourcss.css');?> // css
```

Comment: Unless I did it wrong, this doesn't work. layout.phtml has the `<head>` and it loads before actions, right? So wouldn't this never echo my headlink?

Comment: Make sure your path to the file is like
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('Your path to css folder/cssfile.css');?>

Comment: $this->baseUrl is a variable for my path up to public folder..make sure you change according to that

Comment: My only question is, how come this works? Does Zend get the layout first, and then grab the action views and then output it all at once?

Comment: The Controller - and thus the action - get called before the view process is started. So your view / layout will know which files to render out. That's the most simple form to explain ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simply, do not ECHO `$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($css)` in your view. Personally i only do one `<?=$this->headLink()?>` in my layout.phtml and in all other files its just appending the headLink without echoing it.

Comment: I understand `<?` is short tag. What does `<?=` do? or is that a typo?

Comment: `<?=$something?>` equals `<?php echo $something ?>` so my answer basically is the same as all of the above ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can place the headlink in your actions of controller
for example

here is your action

```
public function indexAction()
{
 $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/basic.css');
}
```

The other way to place the head link in your view as you have done. Its up to you how you use this.
Then in

```
<head>
```

of your layout you can just echo your `headlink` like this

```
echo $this->headStyle();
```